# Rails partial + Unslider JQuery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, slide, partial, unslider

I'm trying to allow users to navigate posts with the idiot/unslider plugin, so I would like to be able to load the posts dynamically.

Here is what I got so far:

> view/show

```
<div class="banner">
<ul id="thelist">
    <li><%= render 'showpost' %></li>
</ul>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('.banner').unslider();
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var unslider = $('.banner').unslider();

$('.unslider-arrow').click(function() {
    var fn = this.className.split(' ')[1];     
    //  Either do unslider.data('unslider').next() or .prev() depending on the className
    unslider.data('unslider')[fn]();
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#thelist").append($("<li> '<%=j render 'showpost' %>' </li>")
})
</script>
```

> view/_showpost

```
<div class="showpartial">
<h4 clas="title">
<%= @post.title %>
</h4>
<br>
<div class="row">
<div class="simplepost">
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">
  <div class="content">
    <p ><%= simple_format(@post.chinese) %></p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="translation">
  <p>
      <%= simple_format(@post.english) %>
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<% @previous = @posts.where(chapter: @post.chapter - 1).first %>
<%= link_to 'Previous', @next, {class: "unslider-arrow prev"} %>

<% @next = @posts.where(chapter: @post.chapter + 1).first %>
<%= link_to 'Next', @next, {class: "unslider-arrow next"} %>





<% if admin? %>
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(@post) %> |
<% end %>
<%= link_to 'Back', posts_path %>

</div>
```

Basically what I would like to do is to append the next post to the slider once the current post is loaded, so that the user can have a nice sliding transition. I wasn't able to find much documentation on this kind of transition, and I am quite new at JQuery so any help is well appreciated!

Thanks